# Can't access Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pip

Hi I am having major trouble with shell.
I am not able to change the path for pip and python.
Python 3.7 is downloaded elsewhere.
Pip has an unknown path. I tried upgrading pip but it stored a blob of code and I don't know what to do with it.
Pandas not available on terminal (shell) which uses python 2.7.

Errors:
ImportError: No module named pandas
After pip install pandas I get the message: Successfully installed numpy-1.19.1 pandas-1.0.5 pytz-2020.1
I still get the message No module named pandas
please help. I have been really frustrated by this!

Comment: Sounds like you're a bit new to python. Have you looked into a virtual environment manager like [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/)? That usually solves a lot of problems when working with multiple python versions.

Comment: I have been running my stuff on anaconda - Jupyter lab and notebook. However, I am trying to learn submlime text and I am trying to run my code directly from it. There is where I am facing problems.

Comment: Make sure you're running sublime text from _inside_ the anaconda environment that has pandas installed. Anaconda is a virtual environment manager; when you eg switch python installations with Anaconda those changes don't affect your whole environment (that is, whole computer), so unless you do your work inside the virtual environment managed by Anaconda, Anaconda won't seem to do anything.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pip3 install yet?

pip could default to the installation of pip for python2 as well.

Finally, if it is doable in your system, you may uninstall python 2 completely as it is out of support anyway, this would save you a lot of headache in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip3 install pandas
```

and if that doesn't work, then try

```
pip install pandas
```

EDIT:

It sounds like you should try to run your code using `python myfile.py` instead of `python3 myfile.py`